# how to pass javascript variable value in separate .js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

we have one external .js file, problem is that, i want to pass my php cat_id value to .js file. so in header i have created one variable, and then i concatenate same variable in .js html string. when i created new row. it does not contain cat_id value in it. please check code and let me know how to fix this issue?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var cat_id = '<?php echo $this->uri->segment(4); ?>';</script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('js/our_custom.js'); ?>"></script>
```

**our_custom.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var cnt = 2;

$("#anc_add").click(function(){

$('#tbl1 tr').last().after('<tr><td><input type="text" name="cat_title[]" value="" placeholder="Enter Title"></td><td><input type="text" name="cat_url[]" value="" placeholder="Enter Url"></td><td><input type="hidden" name="cat_id" value="'+ cat_id +'"></td></tr>');
```

Comment: That should work right there. You are setting the `cat_id` variable in the scope of the `window` so you should be able to access it by `cat_id` in your `our_custom.js`. Have you tried testing this yet?

Comment: yeah, it work, is there any way to pass direct php values in .js?

Comment: You might be able to set a query string on the js file source: http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it global (without "var").

```
<script type="text/javascript"> window.cat_id = '<?php echo $this->uri->segment(4); ?>';</script>
```

insted of

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var cat_id = '<?php echo $this->uri->segment(4); ?>';</script>
```

Comment: is there any way i can direct pass php values in to .js file? or its good way to pass through like this?

Comment: if you don't like this, you can create a global function inside the javascript file. So, after the javascript file import, you can call this function and pass the php variable. Inside the file you should have something like this:

`  var variable;
  globalFunction = function(var) {
       variable = var;
  }; `


And in the php file this:

`
<script type="text/javascript"> var cat_id = '<?php echo $this->uri->segment(4); ?>';</script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('js/our_custom.js'); ?>"></script>

<script>
    globalFunction(cat_id);
</script>

`